# Character recognition specific area

Tags: python, neural-network, ocr

my dataset contains a bunch of license plates of different sizes. I would like to train a convolutional neural network to get the ground truth text of this license plates and only this text. I don't like the network to recognize the country code or advertising text.

[image: license plate]

More precisely, I want the network only to recognize the characters in the red frame and not the country code "CZ" or any other text in this example. Is there a technique to achieve this?

Comment: am not an expert in ocr but first thing that came to my mind is: shouldn't it learn to skip CZ? do you have it included in dataset's labels?

Comment: Hello Marke, no, the country code or all the other unnessecary characters are not included in the labels. Does this make it easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two subproblems here.

The first is [Object Detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_detection), which is how you would identify the part of the image that has the license plate and characters of the license plate. The second problem is [Optical Character Recognition (OCR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition), which is how you would extract the text from the detected regions.

At the time of writing, the [You Only Look Once v3 (YOLOv3)](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/) method is a state of the art for the combination of these two tasks. There is also an ecosystem of tools like Darknet for retraining that model on new problems.

You will need to prepare some training data with example bounding boxes for license plates. Tools like [LabelImg](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg) can help make this process easier.

If you are looking for a walkthrough, this walk through on [Automatic License Plate Detection & Recognition using deep learning](https://towardsdatascience.com/automatic-license-plate-detection-recognition-using-deep-learning-624def07eaaf) looks like it would help you out.

Comment: Hello mcskinner, thank you very much! That helps a lot! Does it make the task easier that the data is labeled and all the "unnecessary" characters are not included in this labels?

Comment: Yes. Having those correct labels will guide the network to understand which parts of the image are important and which are not.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! And this applies for all types of neural networks? Or does it depend on the type?

Comment: For every ML problem you will want the best labeled data you can get, as much of it as you can get, and as accurate to your problem you can get. Of course these do not always align. You may have a small amount of very high quality data but a very large amount of noisy low quality data. When that happens there is no clear best answer, but ideas like Transfer Learning start to become more relevant.